# Why can't I define the constant A0 (some pin) to something?

Tags: programming, c++

What I'm doing wrong or why is it not working:

```
#define Uin A0;

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
  analogRead(Uin);
}
```

Results in a `Error (expected ')' before ; token.`

I thought `#define` just exists as a place holder.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because you have a `;` at the end of your #define.

```
#define Uin A0;
analogRead(Uin);
```

becomes:

```
analogRead(A0;);
```

The Arduino website mentions this in [their reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Define). For more in-depth detail about the C pre-processor you can read the (rather large) manual [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/).

Comment: That's it. Thank you. 

Could you please link to the reference. (It is also answered there - I'm sorry) [In 5 min I can accept the answer]

[link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Define)